# Npgsql pass parameters by name to a stored function

Tags: c#, npgsql, stored-functions, postgresql

I'm working with code I'm converting to Pgsql working with .NET.  I want to call a stored function that has several parameters, but I'd like to bind the parameters by name, like so:

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("\"StoredFunction\"", _Connection)
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add("param2", value2);
command.PArameters.Add("param1", value1);
```

Attempts to do this so far look for a function with parameter types matching in the order in which I added the parameters to the collection, not by name.

Is it possible for Npgsql to bind parameters to stored functions by name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Npgsql doesn't support pass parameters by name. Although it supports receiving out parameter values by name.

Would you mind to fill a bug report about that? So we can track and implement it.

Comment: Having trouble reporting this.  I've registered on the site but reporting the bug isn't working.

Comment: Would you mind to try filling the bug report again. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it does not work with store procedure (CommandType.StoredProcedure).

It does with SQL-text command (CommandType.Text).
You can use :paramname, plus I think in the latest version you can use parameters.addwithvalue(":paramname", param).

You can also use @paramname with the latest version (like MS Sql Server).

Read section "Using parameters in a query " of [this manual](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) for an answer to your original question - but remember what I said above to make your life easier.

Comment: testing with the version of Npgsql available in Q1 2013, I find that the provider seems to support only positional mode parameter passing to functions on the server when client-side the command is in `CommandType.StoredProcedure` mode.  The order in which the parameters are added to the Command's Parameters collection is the order in which they're provided.

Comment: I didn't test with StoredProcedure, it does work with Text though.

Comment: The link to the manual does not work anymore, do you know where it has moved to?